# Displaying an AlertDialog in ViewHolder in a RecyclerView Adapter class

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-viewholder

I've implemented a RecyclerView with some rows and I'm now trying to use AlertDialog to display a message when the user taps on a row.

I've successfully implemented the setOnClickListener in the Adapter but I can't get the AlertDialog to work, the system keeps telling me I can't use AlertDialog.Builder in a ViewHolder:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

My GitHub code is [here](https://github.com/lararufflecoles/RecyclerView100/tree/master/app/src/main/java/es/rufflecol/lara/recyclerview100)

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView textView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView;
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(null);
        {
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("You selected ")
                    .setCancelable(true); // True allows you to use the back button to exit the dialog, false does not
        }
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ended up refactoring with the husband today, updated code is [here](https://github.com/lararufflecoles/RecyclerView100/tree/master/app/src/main/java/es/rufflecol/lara/recyclerview100).

We created an interface and implemented it in the main activity, we then called the method in this interface from a View.OnClickListener set on the itemView.

We add a click listener to the `ViewHolder`:

https://github.com/lararufflecoles/RecyclerView100/blob/master/app/src/main/java/es/rufflecol/lara/recyclerview100/RecyclerAdapter.java#L69

and then make the `Activity` the listener:

https://github.com/lararufflecoles/RecyclerView100/blob/master/app/src/main/java/es/rufflecol/lara/recyclerview100/MainActivity.java#L42

Hopefully this question might help someone else in the future.

Answer (score -2):

Just use

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(itemView.getParent().getContext());
```

Your problem will be resolved.